# QuantLib in CLR

Tags: visual-c++, clr

I use VS2012 (VC11), Boost 1.57, QuantLib 1.4. My goal is to make a Visual CLR project using these libraries in a separate solution than the original QuantLib solution. I started step-by-step to carefully include the libraries, but when I just added the line #include , it gave me the following error:

> metadata operation failed (8013119F) : A TypeRef exists which should,
>   but does not, have a corresponding TypeDef : (OPERATORS_NOT_ALLOWED): (0x0100001b)

Anyone can help?